# Laravel, if I edit all the fields does not work. not saving what edited

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My specialist setting adds and edits in one page. Everything is working
But there is one problem. When I edit everything, it does not save what I edited. I don’t understand why.
Specialist have one to one table (profile_settings).

Profile settings Migration

```
        Schema::create('profile__settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone_number')->nullable();
            $table->string('gender')->nullable();
            $table->string('date_of_birth')->nullable();
            $table->text('about_me')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('country')->nullable();
            $table->string('postal_code')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Profile_Settings Model

```
class Profile_Settings extends Model
{
    // Fill in db
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number',
        'gender', 'date_of_birth', 'about_me',
        'address', 'city', 'country', 'postal_code',
    ];

    // Profile settigns model belongs to User
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

User Model(Specialist)

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public static function countPercent($count, $maxCount){
        //one percent
        $one_percent = $maxCount / 100;
        // $count how much is percent
        $percent = $count / $one_percent;
        return $percent;
    }

    // 1 User have 1 profile settings (ONE TO ONE)
    public function profile_settings(){
        return $this->hasOne(Profile_Settings::class);
    }

}
```

SpecialistDashboardController

```
class SpecialistDashboardController extends Controller
{

    public function dashboard(){
        return view('Frontend.specialists.dashboard.index');
    }

    public function profile_settings(){
        $specialist = Auth::user();
        $data = Auth::user()->profile_settings;
        return view('Frontend.specialists.profile_settings.index', compact('specialist', 'data'));
    }

    public function profile_settings_post(Request $request){
          // Auth Specialist
          $user = Auth::user();
          // Data Specialist Validate
          $data = $request->validate([
              'first_name' => 'nullable|string',
              'last_name' => 'nullable|string',
              'phone_number' => 'nullable|integer',
              'gender' => 'nullable',
              'date_of_birth' => 'nullable',
              'about_me' => 'nullable',
              'address' => 'nullable',
              'city' => 'nullable|string',
              'country' => 'nullable|string',
              'postal_code' => 'nullable|integer',
          ]);

          // If this Specialist no have profile settings data (crate new table in DB)
          if (is_null($user->profile_settings())){
              $new_profile_settings = new Profile_Settings($data);
              $user->profile_settings()->save($new_profile_settings);
          }
          // Else have this Specialist profile settings data (edit and update this table in DB)
          else{
              $user->profile_settings()->update($data);
          }

          // RETURN REDIRECT PROFILE SETTINGS INDEX
        return redirect()->route('frontend.specialist.profile.settings');
    }
}
```

Routes

```
// Front End Routes
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'landing',
], function (){
    //LANDING ROUTS
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index')->name('landing.index');
    //SPECIALIST ROUTS
    Route::get('/specialist', 'SpecialistDashboardController@dashboard')->name('frontend.specialist.dashboard');
    Route::get('/specialist/profile-settings', 'SpecialistDashboardController@profile_settings')->name('frontend.specialist.profile.settings');
    Route::post('/specialist/profile-settings', 'SpecialistDashboardController@profile_settings_post')->name('frontend.specialist.profile.settings.post');
    Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
});
```

Blade Form

```
    <form action="{{route('frontend.specialist.profile.settings.post')}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
            <!-- Basic Information -->
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Basic Information</h4>
                    <div class="row form-row">
                        {{-- Image --}}
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="change-avatar">
                                    <div class="profile-img">
                                        <img src="/frontend/img/doctors/doctor-thumb-02.jpg" alt="User Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="upload-img">
                                        <div class="change-photo-btn">
                                            <span><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload Photo</span>
                                            <input type="file" class="upload">
                                        </div>
                                        <small class="form-text text-muted">Allowed JPG, GIF or PNG. Max size of 2MB</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{-- Username --}}
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Username<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly placeholder="{{$specialist->name}}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{-- Email --}}
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" readonly placeholder="{{$specialist->email}}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{-- First Name --}}
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>First Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{!! !empty($data->first_name) ? $data->first_name : ''!!}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{-- Last Name --}}
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Last Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="{!! !empty($data->last_name) ? $data->last_name : ''!!}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{-- Phone Number --}}
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Phone Number<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phone_number" value="{!! !empty($data->phone_number) ? $data->phone_number : ''!!}" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{-- Gender --}}
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Gender<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <select class="form-control select" name="gender">
                                    <option>{!! !empty($data->gender) ? $data->gender : 'Select'!!}</option>
                                    <option>Male</option>
                                    <option>Female</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{-- Date of Birth --}}
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group mb-0">
                                <label>Date of Birth</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date_of_birth" value="{!! !empty($data->date_of_birth) ? $data->date_of_birth : ''!!}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /Basic Information -->

            <!-- About Me -->
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">About Me</h4>
                    <div class="form-group mb-0">
                        <label>Biography</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="about_me">{!! !empty($data->about_me) ? $data->about_me : ''!!}</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /About Me -->

            <!-- Contact Details -->
            <div class="card contact-card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Contact Details</h4>
                    <div class="row form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Address</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="{!! !empty($data->address) ? $data->address : ''!!}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">City</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" value="{!! !empty($data->city) ? $data->city : ''!!}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" value="{!! !empty($data->country) ? $data->country : ''!!}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Postal Code</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="postal_code" value="{!! !empty($data->postal_code) ? $data->postal_code : ''!!}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /Contact Details -->

            <div class="submit-section submit-btn-bottom">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn">Save Changes</button>
            </div>
    </form>
```

// Screen
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKcVt.png

Comment: can you elaborate more on what is not saved (the particular fields). You say it works, but it doesn't.

Comment: It works if I edit at least 1 field. If I edit all the fields that I edited, it is not saved.

Comment: As with the answer below, seems you validation is failing. You need to check that the validation passes and handle the appropriate pass/fail cases as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$request->validate()` can be problematic. if validation fails, it attempts to return to the previous page, which isn't always what we want. Try to do it this way instead.

```
          // Auth Specialist
          $user = Auth::user();
          $data => $request->input(); //returns array of all input values.
          // You might want to use only() instead so as to specify the keys you need

          // Data Specialist Validate
          $rules = [
              'first_name' => 'nullable|string',
              ...
              'postal_code' => 'nullable|integer',
          ]);

        $validation = validator($data, $roles);

        if($validation->fails()) {
             // do what you wish with the error
            return back()->withErrors($validate->errors());
            //return response($validation->errros());
        }
```

Comment: Thank for much. Errors was a Validate input.

Answer (score 0):

change to create

```
          if (is_null($user->profile_settings())){
              $user->profile_settings()->create($data);
          }
```

or change to firstOrCreate (I'm less confident about this option)

```
$profile = $user->profile_settings()->firstOrCreate($data);
$profile->save();
```

then you don't need to query the relationship and can remove the if statement